# Celery: Be sure to commit the transaction for each poll iteration

Tags: celery, django-celery

I'm using django-celery and have set things up so I can call a task from the interactive shell, the task completes (as evidenced by celery log) and i see the result in celeryd output.

However, I seem unable to ever get the result of the task in the shell where I start the task:

```
>>> from mymodule.tasks import testTask
>>> res = testTask.delay()
>>> testTask.ready()
False

@task
def testTask():
logger.info('LOGGER: start task')
time.sleep(10)
logger.info('LOGGER: stop task')
return 5
```

I'm assuming this is due to the following error which I sometimes get:

```
TxIsolationWarning: Polling results with transaction isolation level repeatable-read within the same transaction may give outdated results. Be sure to commit the transaction for each poll iteration.
```

My question, how to I commit the transaction and where is this done?  Also, what is the issue here?  Celery trying to access the info from mysql whilst Django has locked the table?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check transaction isolation level if you use MySQL as broker.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#mysql-is-throwing-deadlock-errors-what-can-i-do

Comment: Ok, i edited my.cnf to read transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED and everything is working.  Thanks!